# r Converting elements of a dataframe to multilevel list

Tags: r, list

I have a dataset which is as shown below

```
id        Description           Value       Date             Indicator
462269    Toyota                9.23        2013-10-21       Post
462269    Toyota                57.45       2013-07-11       None
462269    Ford                  32.95       2013-01-25       Pre
462269    Mazda                 12.29       2013-04-13       None
462269    Chevy                 11.24       2013-05-12       Pre
806284    Toyota                12.11       2014-05-15       Pre
806284    Mazda                 12.56       2014-04-16       Pre
806284    Hyundai               89.95       2014-09-15       Pre
806284    Chevy                 18.74       2014-02-19       Post
953303    Toyota                4.83        2012-08-14       Post
953303    Mazda                 95.46       2012-04-04       None
953303    Mazda                 12.78       2012-03-17       Pre

df = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("462269", "806284", "953303"), class = "factor"), 
    Description = structure(c(5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    1L, 5L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Chevy", "Ford", "Hyundai", "Mazda", 
    "Toyota"), class = "factor"), Value = structure(c(11L, 9L, 
    7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 5L), .Label = c("11.24", 
    "12.11", "12.29", "12.56", "12.78", "18.74", "32.95", "4.83", 
    "57.45", "89.95", "9.23", "95.46"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(8L, 
    7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2012-03-17", 
    "2012-04-04", "2012-08-14", "2013-01-25", "2013-04-13", "2013-05-12", 
    "2013-07-11", "2013-10-21", "2014-02-19", "2014-04-16", "2014-05-15", 
    "2014-09-15"), class = "factor"), Indicator = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("None", 
    "Post", "Pre"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "Description", 
"Value", "Date", "Indicator"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to convert this dataset into a multi-level list where `ID` is the main list element , `Description` is the second level nested under each `ID` and `Value, Date, Indicator` are third level elements. The desired output is as as shown below

```
462269    

    Toyota
            Value       Date            Indicator
            9.23        2013-10-21      Post
            57.45       2013-07-11      None    
    Hyundai     
            Value       Date            Indicator
                NA      NA              NA
    Mazda            
            Value       Date            Indicator
            12.29       2013-04-13      None
    Chevy          
            Value       Date            Indicator
            11.24       2013-05-12      Pre
    Ford     
            Value       Date            Indicator
            32.95       2013-01-25      Pre

806284    

    Toyota
            Value       Date            Indicator
            12.11       2014-05-15      Pre 
    Hundai     
            Value       Date            Indicator
            89.95       2014-09-15      Pre
    Mazda            
            Value       Date            Indicator
            12.56       2014-04-16      Pre
    Chevy          
            Value       Date            Indicator
            18.74       2014-02-19      Post
        Ford     
            Value       Date            Indicator
            NA          NA              NA
953303    

    Toyota
            Value       Date            Indicator
            4.83        2012-08-14      Post
    Hundai     
            Value       Date            Indicator
            NA          NA              NA  
    Mazda            
            Value       Date            Indicator
            95.46       2012-04-04      None
            12.78       2012-03-17      Pre
    Chevy          
            Value       Date            Indicator
                NA      NA              NA
    Ford     
            Value       Date            Indicator
                NA      NA              NA
```

I like to emphasize that the third level elements (Value, Date, Indicator)

```
  ....     Value       Date            Indicator
           9.23        2013-10-21      Post
           57.45       2013-07-11      None 
  .....
```

should be in a matrix format.

Any help on accomplishing this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your purpose for data processing in a list-like fashion, or for displaying in some report?

Comment: It might be that `split(df, list(df$Description, df$id), drop = TRUE)` is a good start, though it provides more of the *structure* to move forward, not necessarily a "pretty product".

Comment: @r2evans, goal is to process the data in a list like format and your solution was great but it is not what I was looking for, for example your approach is combining id and description together and the second level elements are are id, description, value date indicator but this is not the desired output, thanks though :)

Comment: The point was that `split` is what you need. @koundy appears to have captured the gist of it, so go ahead and "accept" it, they went the extra step beyond my comment.

Comment: @r2evans you are absolutely right :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` twice would create nested list structure You wanted.

```
lapply(split(df, df$id),function(x) split(x,x$Description))
```

Comment: this is excellent, in the third level where the `Value, Date , Indicator` values are displayed for each `ID` and `Description` combination I am also seeing `Id` and `Description` column values again. How do I get rid of these `id`and `Description` values in the third level list elements ?  Thanks Kaoundy.